# using UNC path in a For Loop in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, command-line

I have a command line program in a batch file.
The step i am having an issue with is as follows:
This works:

assuming echo %filestocopyfilter%  produces this:
*.sc *.csv   (verified)

the following works:

```
d:

cd d:\temp

for %%i in (%filestocopyfilter%) do (

 set FileName=%%i

 SET FTIME=%%~ti

)
```

This produces all of the  file names ending in .sc or .csv

the trouble is I need a UNC path, e.g.   \10.10.0.145\d$\temp

now I can no longer use d: or cd d:\temp
without these the UNC path does not work in the for command above.

I have tried to modify something I found on this site to get this:

```
for %%i in ('dir "\\10.10.0.145\d$\temp\%filestocopyfilter%" ') do (

 set FileName=%%i

 SET FTIME=%%~ti

)
```

it fails.

Also tried

```
for %%i in ('dir "\\10.10.0.145\d$\temp\*.sc" ') do (

 set FileName=%%i

 SET FTIME=%%~ti

)
```

this would of course only get *.sc files but it fails also.

Any ideas appreciated.

### Btw the reason i must use UNC is because i am running this batch file from another computer using psexec.  the batch file runs locally fine but it will not see a mapped letter drive like q:\temp  (where q is 10.10.0.145) because it does not have appropriate permissions. I did find that if I have the batch file disconnect and then remap the drive using the login credentials it will work - however It is really not good to be disconnecting and re-connecting the drive at the time this needs to run.

-modified - added to the original question - will not fit in comments -

First of all thank you for the prompt answers.
This has given me a lot of things to try.

Note: these are all running in a batch file not command line directly:

Here I tried splitting up the filters each with a path - it doesnt crash put the echo results are empty FileName and FTIME are blank.
again this works with a non UNC path as long as I do this first (%driveletter% = d:) and (%sourcepathnoquotes% = d:\temp)
---------------------works-----------------------

%driveletter%

cd %sourcepathnoquotes%

FOR   %%i IN (*.csv *.sc) DO.....

--------------Does not work-------------------

FOR   %%i IN (' "\10.10.0.11\d$\u1\static\source-erase*.csv" "\10.10.0.11\d$\u1\static\source-erase*.sc" ') DO (

set FileName=%%~dpi

SET FTIME=%%~ti

echo the file name is %FileName%

echo the file time is %FTIME%

)

pause

Another related area I am having trouble with is here with WMIC

Assuming %sourcepathdoubleslashnoquotes% = \10.10.0.11\d$\u1\static\source-erase

Assuming %FileName% = myfile.sc

wmic datafile where name="%sourcepathdoubleslashnoquotes%%FileName%" get lastmodified > "%tmpfilepathnoquotesnodouble%tmpFile.txt"

THis works with non UNC path

type "%tmpfilepathnoquotesnodouble%tmpFile.txt" | findstr /v LastModified > "%tmpfilepathnoquotesnodouble%tmpFile2.txt"

set /p myvar= < "%tmpfilepathnoquotesnodouble%tmpFile2.txt"

del "%tmpfilepathnoquotesnodouble%tmpFile.txt"

del "%tmpfilepathnoquotesnodouble%tmpFile2.txt"

Note:  the reason I am writing this to tmpFile.txt and tmpFile2.txt is because the results of the WMIC command are two lines:

LastModified

20150505172747.167788-240

I need only the second line in a variable - I cannot seem to output the 2nd line of the command into a variable without writing to a file first

Regarding Pushd: It does work but I have two problems.

1) I need the file name reported back as well. It currently just reports MMDDYYY HH:MM:SS AM/PM

2) it would be easier to work with the time stamp of WMIC  see above.

3) Can't seem to get it to populate a variable so that I can parse and manipulate

pushd "\computer.example.com\d$\temp\"
forfiles -m *.csv -c "cmd /c echo @fdate @ftime"
popd

Ideas?
Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 3):

`pushd` and `popd` are going to help you here. They push a directory onto a stack and change into that directory, then you can pop back to your previous location. The neat trick is that they reserve a drive letter for UNC paths for you behind the scenes (when I tried it, they allocated 'Z' drive). Have a look at the following example:

```
pushd "\\computer.example.com\d$\temp\"
forfiles -m *.csv -c "cmd /c echo @fdate @ftime"
popd
```

Comment: Did you try it? The problem is that `for /F ... in ('dir ...` loop treats file *names*, not file *objects*. Hence, `%%~dpi` always results to current working directory and `%%~ti` is not defined if such file doesn't exist. `/S` switch helps on local  paths (don't know what about UNCs at the moment). And use `"delims="` rather than `"tokens=*"` as for potential leading space(s) in a particular file name. Rare but possible...

Answer (score 0):

```
For %A in (\\serenity\C$\*.bat \\serenity\C$\*.txt) do echo %A
```

If you use multiple file specs you have to specify full path to each one for all commands that takes them like `for`, `dir`, `del`.

Also `C$` is only available to administrators. So you have to be elevated to use it.

Use this command to CD to the UNC folder

Turn on ability to do so

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v DisableUNCCheck /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

then

```
start "" /d \\serenity\C$ "cmd"
```

or

```
start "" /b /d \\serenity\C$ "cmd"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
pushd "\\10.10.0.145\d$\temp"
```

and then use your (locally working) script. By [Command-Line Reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340.aspx):

> If you specify a network path, the `pushd` command temporarily assigns
>   the highest unused drive letter (starting with `Z:`) to the specified
>   network resource. The command then changes the current drive and
>   directory to the specified directory on the newly assigned drive. If
>   you use the `popd` command with command extensions enabled, the `popd`
>   command removes the drive-letter assignation created by `pushd`.

Sorry if it will not work through `psexec`.